# División por zero en php

Tags: php

tengo una función que me calcula los likes y dislikes, para luego hacer un for con estrellas para el tema del rating. Pero tengo el problema de que si tiene 0 likes y 0 dislikes, luego al dividir salta un error de división por cero:

Esta es mi función:

```
function devolverRating($likes,$dislikes){
  return round($likes/($likes+$dislikes)*5);
}
```

Y el for con el que pinto las estrellas en función del rating que me devuelve, pero hay veces que a lo mejor me devuelve un 2 y me pinta las 5 estrellas o que tiene de rating 0 y me pinta 5 estrellas, sin contar lo de división por cero:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
  if($i<=$rating){
   echo "<i class='fas fa-star'></i>";
  }
  else{
   echo"<i class='far fa-star'></i>";
  } 
}
```

Comment: Y que dice el error que obtienes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
function devolverRating($likes,$dislikes){
  $r=0;
  if(($likes+$dislikes)>0)
    $r=round($likes/($likes+$dislikes)*5);
  return $r;
}
```

Y así:

```
for($i=0;$i<=$rating;$i++)
   echo "<i class='fas fa-star'></i>";
```

Comparando ambos códigos veras la diferencia. Si te surge cualquier duda, déjala en los comentarios.

Comment: En este caso en el for solo pintas las estrellas rellenas ? Lo digo para hacer contraste entre estrellas completas y las que no, no se si me explico.

Comment: Ah, pues entonces tu código está bien... no me había fijado en que mostrabas estrellas diferentes. ¿Estás seguro que `$rating` vale lo que crees que vale? ¿Lo has mostrado para asegurarte?

Comment: si, lo que pasa es que con las pruebas que hago son con 0 likes y 0 dislikes o 1 likes y 0 dislikes. Hago suposiciones exageradas de si hay muchos más, pero si es 0 me salta el error de división entre 0, o que el rating me devuelve 2 y me pinta 4 estrellas rellenas.

Comment: Pero la división por cero ya está arreglada con la respuesta que te he dado, ¿no?

Comment: Perdón por tardar, si funciona. Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yo pienso que para la división por cero deberías comprobar antes de dividir, por ejemplo:

```
function devolverRating($likes, $dislikes){
    if($likes > 0){
        //Hacemos división
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, yo haría la siguiente operación para obtener el número de estrellas (donde 0 estrellas es lo más bajo y 5 estrellas es el tope):

```
$stars = (($likes - $dislikes) / $likes) * 100 / 20;
```

Por ejemplo, si $likes == 10000 y $dislikes == 2100 el resultado es 3.95.

Ese resultado se debería usar para "pintar" las estrellas.

Comment: En este caso si hay más likes que dislikes funciona, pero en caso de que haya más dislikes ya no da un resultado muy correcto.

Comment: Si, en caso de haber mas dislikes entonces dará un número negativo `$likes - $dislikes`, en dado caso el `ranking` parece estar definido.